# How do I automatically remove the lines across the midrib which a river doesn't overlap?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing

I have a river line, mid-rib and transect line

[image]

I am trying to get a transect line by keeping mid-rib as the reference and I need to include only the transect lines that overlap the river.

Just like this

[image]

Here I split the transect line using the midrib and included only the lines which lie over the river layer.

How do I achieve the same results automatically if I have several watersheds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "Split with lines", "Select by location" and "Extract selected features" tools respectively.

1. Split with lines

[image]

2. Select by location

[image]

3. Extract selected features

[image]

Result:

[image]